# UITableViewController not showing cells in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**UPDATE**

When I hold-click onto the simulator, that's only when the separators appear.

**UPDATE OVER**

I am creating an app based upon `UITableViewController`. The first thing I did was embed my `UITableViewController` in a `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController`.

Each time I run my iOS Simulator, the cells/data are not showing up.

FYI, I am using Swift.

Here is my main VC code:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 0
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel.text = newsItems[indexPath.row].title
    cell.dateLabel.text = newsItems[indexPath.row].date
    cell.mainLabel.text = newsItems[indexPath.row].main

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you've used

Comment: @VictorSigler I shared it :)

Comment: Could you please also format your question a bit better, I don’t really know what is your question is here... :)

Answer (score 1):

You set wrong number of items in section

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return newsItems.count
}
```

Try to return more than 0 items to be shown in `UITableView`

To configure separator line in `UITableView` try to use properties.
[image]

Comment: The data has now shown, but there are no cell separators.

Comment: This feature is going to be configured at storyboard or add more than 1 items

Comment: What feature in storyboard?

Comment: I haven't tampered with the cell separators, they should show.

Answer (score 0):

As @Oleg answer , you're setting a number zero in the `UITableViewDataSource` function `numberOfRowsInSection`, the correct way of do it this is assign the number of elements of your `dataSource` in your case as I saw in you code using the `newsItems.count`, see the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return newsItems.count
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I have done this now, but there are no cell separators.

Comment: @AnnabelleSykes Have you touched anything in your Storyboard regarding the `UITableViewController` separators?

Comment: All I did was give it its custom class, and embed it in a `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate number of row in table view. Put your items Count in return.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return newsItems.count;
}
```

Comment: I have done this now, but there are no cell separators.

Answer (score 0):

Number of rows in section tells the compiler that your table view has how many rows in one section
return 0 means you have 0 rows to display

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return newsItems.count
}
```

Comment: I have fixed this now, but I can't see the cell separators.